# How to generate content based on spring-security user rights

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security, user-roles

I want to generate some html content based on the user rights of a user who logged in with spring-security. I can't find much about this subject on the internet so far and i'm wondering what would be a good way to implement this.

So far i was thinking about making a custom tag, attach it to a controller who links to a class that can generate, for example, the menu. I'm just not sure how get the user roles/rights of the user from spring-security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
...
<body>

Shared content for all roles.
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('roleName1')">
    content for roleName1
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('roleName2')">
    content for roleName2
</sec:authorize>
More shared content for all roles.
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the spring security tags to create dynamic content based on user roles. [Spring Security Taglibs reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html).